# How can I give focus to a grid in a Windows 10 UWP app?

Tags: windows-10, uwp, c++-cx

How can I give focus to a grid in a Windows 10 UWP app? It seems like it does not have a focus member.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Layout controls don't provide a focus method.

Only controls deriving from the `Control` class have a [`Focus` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702161.aspx).

Layout controls (e.g. `Grid`, `StackPanel` or `Canvas`) derive from the [`Panel` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.panel.aspx). This class doesn't provide the capability to "focus" something, because the control itself just layouts its child elements.

You could also say, only an `UIElement` that is also a `TabStop` can be focused.